# What is the best practice for saving data in Ubuntu one db from mobile?

Tags: ubuntu-one, application-development, ubuntu-touch, qml

I'm doing a simple todo-list with QML for Ubuntu phone OS. Is there any standard way for accessing Ubuntu One Database to sync data?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There will be; we're working on it. I plan to have the QML U1DB declarative API published soon.

In the meantime, until that arrives, you may find [this code](https://code.launchpad.net/~sil/+junk/u1notebrowser-quickly) interesting; it is a simple notes app, but written with QML and using U1DB. This U1DB QML addition follows the declarative QML U1DB API I mentioned above, but it's a Python-based prototype of that API. So, it's very very hacky indeed, and will be replaced with a proper U1DB QML setup as part of the Ubuntu SDK, but you may find it useful to experiment with. In particular, you'll see from [this code](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~sil/+junk/u1notebrowser-quickly/view/head:/data/ui/u1notebrowser-large.qml#L444) how to declaratively declare a U1DB database, indexes, documents, and queries, and from [this code](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~sil/+junk/u1notebrowser-quickly/view/head:/data/ui/u1notebrowser-large.qml#L89) that a U1DBQuery is a ListModel. That code should give you some idea of how you will be able to use U1DB from QML in Ubuntu Phone, although I must repeat that the *implementation* of that API from Python is a hacky prototype.

Comment: Feel like updating this now that the QML plugin actually exists?